# Angular Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm getting an error, and im not sure what the problem is

> angular.js:14642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

I'm trying to update a post asynchronously. I can add, get, delete posts asynchronously just need to do it for the update function.

main.js

```
$scope.updatePost = function(post){

    $http.post('/auth/upost/' + post.id, {
        body: $scope.post.body, 
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.myposts.push(data.data);
    });



};
```

**Route**

`Route::post('auth/upost/{post}', 'PostController@update')->name('update.post');`

PostController.php

```
public function update(Post $post)
{
    //
    $data = request()->validate([
        'body' => 'required|string'
    ]);


    $post->update($data);

    $response = new Response(json_encode($post));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    return $response;

}
```

**html**

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">
        <figure>
            <p ng-model="post.body" editable-text="post.body" e-form="textBtnForm"> <% post.body %></p>
            <p>  <% post.created_at %></p>
        </figure>
        <span>

         <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-if="post.deletable"></i>

              <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
                edit
              </button>
            <span><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatePost(post)">Update</button></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need  body: $scope.body,?

Comment: i need to pass the updated body content, what do you think i should i do ?

Comment: what about  $http.post('/auth/upost/' + post.id, {
        body: post, 
    })

Comment: @Sajeetharan i get this now `angular.js:12701 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/upost/36 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Comment: i get this 
`{body: ["The body must be a string."]}`

Comment: i figured it out, i did 

`body: post.body` and it updates but it render a new post

i fixed it

i had to remove

`$scope.myposts.push(data.data);`

Comment: thank you :) sajee

Answer (score 0):

correct code, i had to remove the $scope, not sure why but it works.

**Main.js**

```
$scope.updatePost = function(post){

    $http.post('/auth/upost/' + post.id, {
        body: post.body

    }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);  


    });




};
```